# creating a user area on a rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, github

I was wondering if someone could give me some guidance on the best next steps to take as i am still learning rails. Basically as it stands i have a website that allows a user to register, sign in, sign out and edit their profile. I did that with devise for the authentication.I have an admin area to the website for the website owners not the public. I chose to do it this way as it is an e commerce site and i want the user section more heavily customised. I now want to create pages the following pages.

A status page for the user to see their order history,
A rewards page for coupon redemption,
A page for the user to see what subcriptions they are currently signed up to.

I have included my user code below but if anyone could give me some help as to approaching this it would be most appreciated as i cant quite get my head around the best next step!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable


  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
  # # a listings existence depends on the existence of the user that created it
  # has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
  has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emma - welcome to Rails! First of all, StackOverflow is really for specific programming questions. I understand you need some idea as to which path to go down, so here's what I'd do:

---

**Devise**

Since you're using Devise (great gem), let me give you some information on how it works.

Devise is an [authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) system - meaning that it handles the registration, login and session maintenance of your app. Specifically, when using Devise, it will just be used as a way to manage *access* to your app. IE don't worry about Devise

You'll find a [great resource on Devise / Authentication here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise):

[image]

---

**Functionality**

As per your question, the *functionality* of your system should be contained in the admin area. Creating this is actually relatively simple (all the heavy lifting done by Devise):

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   root: "application#dash"
   resources :orders
   resources :products
end

root: "products#index"
resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
```

This will give you the ability to use the following code:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   #No authentication required
   def index
      @products = Product.all
   end

   def show
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Notice the above controller doesn't have any authentication? It's simply used to give you the ability to show the products / product to the users. This is the "front end", and can be used for everything from your "products" to "pages" etc

The functionality you're looking for lies in the "backend" - the "admin" area. We achieve this by using the [`:admin` namespace](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), which basically gives us a folder where our admin-centric controllers will live:

```
#app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def dash
      #stuff here
   end
end

#app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::ApplicationController
    ....
end
```

The beauty of this is that the `admin` namespace will ostensibly be "self contained" (with `admin/application_controller` managing the authentication, and the child controllers inheriting from it).

Specifics aside, this should give you a stable platform to move forward from.

--

**Resources**

Here are some good resources:

> - [Simple Rails backend (HIGHLY recommended)](http://www.iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1)
> - [Creating a Rails admin area from scratch](http://everydayrails.com/2012/07/31/rails-admin-panel-from-scratch.html)
> - [Railscasts Administration information](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=9)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately i have already done everything above which is why i am a bit stuck as to where to go next. Asking on here as a last resort after much reading.

Comment: Well please detail what errors you're receiving etc - I can't read your mind - what's the problem? You posted a `User` model, so what do you want me to do?

Comment: I really appreciate your help but i had not realised this is not something i can ask here as it is not so specific. I need to create the pages listed but having already done everything you suggested i am just very stuck on how to go forward.

Comment: do you mean you need to create the pages in your views ?